# Parse login with facebook always returning null

Tags: android, parsing, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

it's my third day trying to make a login with facebook and with parse as a backend.
I did all the things cited here:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android
step by step: implementation,
initializing parse and ParseFacebookUtils,
keyhash,
relying app facebook id to parse,
enabling my app to public access
..
I still got these error:Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.
There are many people who had the same issue, but no one was similar to mine.However there is one and only that seems interesting to me:

> SOLVED: After a lot of attempts, the trick was a support.jar, specifically android-support-v4.jar. This comes with the new latest Facebook SDK but is not standard on your project. Use the Facebook one that is in their SDK and copy it into your libs folder and link.

and since i got this line in my builde.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

it may be the cause, but the thing is that i'm using a lot this library so i cannot delete it!

```
Builde.gradle:
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
```

and in my libs folder i have thoses jar files:
commons-ui-2.4,
gson 2.2.4 ,
Parse 1.9.2 ,
ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.4, 
picasso 2.5.2 ,
volley